# Oracle JDK 11 Install and Setting to Default (NOT openJDK)

Tags: package-management, software-installation, java, jdk, openjdk

I have installed openJDK but want to default to regular JDK 11 (not OpenJDK). Steps I have taken:

1)`java -version`

> openjdk version "11.0.7" 2020-04-14 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
>   11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-2ubuntu219.10) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-2ubuntu219.10, mixed mode, sharing)`

2) `sudo apt-get install oracle-java11-set-default-local`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package oracle-java11-set-default-local is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'oracle-java11-set-default-local' has no installation
```

3) `update-java-alternatives -l`

> java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64      1111
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64

4) Is it possible that I should just set the package installer to /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.7, instead of java-11-oracle? Top part of screenshot is the .deb file I downloaded from Oracle's site. Bottom part is what is saved in /usr/lib/jvm
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problems setting up Java on Ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1228991/problems-setting-up-java-on-ubuntu-19-10)

Comment: @Raffa Thanks, but no.  When I try `sudo update-alternatives --config java`  the result is: ```There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java): /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
Nothing to configure.```

Comment: Then it looks like you have not installed Oracle Java correctly, see the instructions on the PPA page. You need to download installer from Oracle manually and place it the path described by package installer.

Comment: @N0rbert - thanks would you kindly check #4 above before I go that route?  I already downloaded the .deb file from Oracle and believe it's installed?

Comment: The linuxuprising's installer expects that you have downloaded `jdk-11.0.7_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz` and placed it in location, see updated answer.

Comment: @N0rbert I have downloaded jdk-11.0.7_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz and placed it into /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local, but now when I run `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java`  I get an error **Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu eoan InRelease
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu'**

Comment: possibly sdkman would help -- not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow openjdk was overwritting jdk, so I put /app/lang/java/jdk-11.0_64 at the end of my .bashrc file and it's fixed

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to install package from PPA, but forgot to add [the PPA](https://launchpad.net/~linuxuprising/+archive/ubuntu/java).

So you have to do the following:

Download the `jdk-11.0.7_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz` from https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk11-downloads.html and copy it to cache location

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local
sudo cp jdk-11.0.7_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local/

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall oracle-java11-set-default-local
```

and then reboot.

---

To force Oracle Jave default use

```
sudo update-java-alternatives --set /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle
```

Comment: Thanks! I ran this. How do I check to ensure default is now java instead of openjdk. Do I do this in the IDE (Netbeans)? When running java -version I see  ```openjdk version "11.0.7" 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-2ubuntu219.10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-2ubuntu219.10, mixed mode, sharing)```

Comment: It says the file doesn't exist. I checked and this directory exists but is empty:   `sudo update-java-alternatives --set /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle`
**update-java-alternatives: file does not exist: /usr/lib/jvm/.java-11-oracle.jinfo**